# How can I append a character to an array of characters?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, data-structures, decode

I'm trying to do a decoder. Inputs are L, C, lungime_cod (length of code) and S.

Where L are the letters, C are the codes for every letter, length of code is the length of the code for every letter (all have to be equal) and S is the coded message I receive.

In my example letter A has the code 000; N has the code 001; etc

I'm trying to compare characters stored in 'cod' (string that changes so I can compare every code) with every 3 other characters in S that are stored in 'car' so I can see what the message is.

I get these error when I run :

Error   C2664   'char *strncat(char *,const char *,size_t)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'char' to 'char *'

Error   E0167   argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

I get these appear because of different data structure but I can't find how to do it.

```
int main()
{
    char L[] = { 'A', 'N', '_', 'R', 'E', 'M', '.' };
    char C[] = { '000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110' };
    int lungime_cod = 3;
    char S[] = { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0' };
    int lungime_text = size(S);
    int lungime_bin = size(C)
    int stop = lungime_text / lungime_cod;
    string msj= {};
    for (int i = 0; i <= stop; i = i + lungime_cod)
    {
        char car = {};
        for (int j = 0; j <= lungime_cod; j++)
        {
            strncat(car, S[i + j], 1);
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= lungime_bin; k = k + lungime_cod)
        {
            char cod = {};
            for (int l = 1; l <= lungime_cod; l++)
            {
                strncat( cod , C[k + l], 1);
            }
            if (car == cod)
                msj = msj + L[k];
            else
                msj = msj;
        }


    }

    std::cout << msj;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Functions like `strncat` are for C-style strings, not arrays of characters (and definitely not for single characters!). You should use C++ strings if you want strings or C++ collections of characters (like `std::vector<char>`) if you want collections of characters.

Comment: You do not understand characters and strings. This might help you: [https://daveparillo.github.io/intermediate-cpp/string+vector/string.html](https://daveparillo.github.io/intermediate-cpp/string+vector/string.html).

Comment: As currently declared, `car` and `cod` are not arrays but only single characters. Hence the error about "cannot convert argument 1 from 'char' to 'char *'"